# Compare list of words to Series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of words and i have large series and I want to compare each word in the list to how many rows each word appears in.

```
def example(word_list, Series):
   df['0'].value_counts()
```

As far as i got was above which only counts the amount of words in total, not how many rows each word in the list appears in.
example

the - 6 rows

house - 2 rows

Comment: Add an example input and the expected output to strengthen your post.

Comment: No, its mutiple words per line

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = np.array(['hello friend','this','is Anna coming?','hello there!'])

ser = pd.Series(data)


my_l = ['hello', 'is']
d = {}
for word in my_l:

  count = 0

  for s in ser:
    if (' ' + word + ' ') in (' ' + s + ' '):
      count = count +1
  d[word] = count

print (d)
```

output

```
{'hello': 2, 'is': 1}
```

Comment: @Hammy I've just edited it so it will work with any sentence

Answer (score 1):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['data'], data=['what are you doing', 'give me the the file', 'the sun comes up up', 'you and me'])
word_list = ['the', 'up', 'me']
df['words'] = df['data'].str.split().apply(lambda i: list(set(i))) # making sure a word occurs only once per row
all_words = [i for j in df['words'].values.tolist() for i in j]
d = {}
for i in word_list:
    d[i] = all_words.count(i)

d
{'the': 2, 'up': 1, 'me': 2}
```

Even though there are three occurrences of 'the', only two row occurrences so output is 2

Answer (score 1):

Using @Ram setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['data'], data=['what are you doing', 'give me the the file', 'the sun comes up up', 'you and me'])
word_list = ['the', 'up', 'me']

df['data'].str.split(expand=True).stack().groupby(level=0)\
 .apply(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates().value_counts())\
 .sum(level=1)[word_list]
```

Output:

```
the    2
up     1
me     2
dtype: int64
```

---

Or using @Alex setup:

```
data = np.array(['hello friend','this','is Anna coming?','hello there!'])

ser = pd.Series(data)

my_l = ['hello', 'is']

ser.str.split(expand=True).stack().groupby(level=0)\
     .apply(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates().value_counts())\
     .sum(level=1)[my_l]
```

Output:

```
hello    2
is       1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: this is a good way to, but I wanted to count a word once per row, so the should be only 2 rows shown in not 3.

Answer (score 0):

what about simply:

`{word:series.str.contains(word).sum() for word in word_list}` ?